# Compass: grunt-contrib-compass not support multiple browser gradient background

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass

My Gruntfile configuration is:

```
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    // generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    // javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    // fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    // importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    // httpImagesPath: '/images',
    // httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    // httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    // relativeAssets: false,
    // assetCacheBuster: false,
    // raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
    }
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: true
    }
  }
}
```

My SCSS file is:

```
@import "compass/css3";

.toolbar {
    @include box-shadow(#555 0px 0px 5px 0px);
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(top, #666666, #333333));
}
```

The generated CSS file is:

```
.toolbar {
    box-shadow: #555555 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #666666, #333333);
}
```

Multiple browser supporting is lost...
But, the strange thing is when I build a project by `compass create xxx`, and copy the SCSS above, then run `compass compile xxx`, everything is ok!

Why? Is there something wrong with grunt-contrib-compass?

Comment: You do realize code is being compiled to the .tmp folder, right?